# Define my own read macro

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, reader-macro

There are some read macros in Common Lisp such as `'` `#'` `#P`, but how can I write a read macro?

Like this:

```
#T"hello world"
====================>
(gettext "hello world")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [set-macro-character](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_set_ma.htm#set-macro-character) and [set-dispatch-macro-character](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_set__1.htm), for example after:

```
(set-dispatch-macro-character #\# #\T
  (lambda (s c n)
    `(gettext ,(read s t nil t))))
==> T
```

you can use the installed read syntax

```
(read-from-string "#T\"this is a test\"")
==> (GETTEXT "this is a test")
```